# Question on normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hello all I was given this question in my linear algebra class which I have tried to solve but to no avail, and I would really appreciate any help.
I am given a matrix $ A \in M_{nxn}(C) $ and am asked to prove that if A commutes in multiplication with the matrix $ AA^* $ then A is normal, with the given hint to look at A as linear complex operator on $ C^n $ and to look at A restricted to the eigenspaces of $ AA^* $.
My problem is I have no idea how to incorporate the hint into some solution to obtain A is normal. Any help would be appreciated as I have tried to solve it but cannot even know where to start. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear but perhaps this might help.
You are given A(AA*) = (AA*)A , so by associativity : 
           A(AA*-A∗A) = 0 
and the definition of normal is AA*-A*A = 0, so we have to get from the
matrix expression above to the expression AA * -A*A = 0

Let {D0,D1,D2....Dn} be the n-vectors which span the eigenspace of AA* , then
we have : 
    A(AA*-A*A)Di = xiDi  where x is the eigenvalue for the eigenvector Di 
I think the next step is to show that given any vector v (!=0):

```
A(AA*-A*A)v = 0 this would imply either A=0 or AA*-A*A = 0
```

Here's a hint, perhaps you can express v as a linear combination of the eigenvectors Di's and then show that your v isn't 0 but is mapped into 0
by the matrix expression, so that implies A is normal.  Sorry I'm a bit tired, but I hope you can review your class notes and see the penny drop!.